# Change date format in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice

I have a column with date values with initial value as: '01.02.13' (in format DD.MM.YY) . Converted it to the required format (DD.MM.YYYY) '01.02.2013'. But when I **focus** on the cell it shows date as '02/01/2013' . How to change this value so that it shows in the desired format on focus as well.

Comment: This looks as if the locale/language might not be set to the desired locale?

Answer (score 1):

Mark the column and klick "Format | Cells" choosing one of the possible Date formats which will be presented in the opening menu. (Libr Office Calc 3.5.x)